# Error when importing cytoscape-automove in React application

Tags: cytoscape.js

I installed **cytoscape-automove** via npm: `npm i --save cytoscape-automove`

Inside my React app, I get the following error when importing the module: `import automove from 'cytoscape-automove';`.

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'cytoscape-automove'. 
'/home/sheereen/......../node_modules/cytoscape-automove/cytoscape-automove.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/cytoscape-automove` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'cytoscape-automove';
```

tried importing `npm i --save-dev @types/cytoscape-automove` as per the suggestion, but give 404 Not found